# Not able to create envelope and send envelope from Signer Account. Invalid Template ID error coming

Tags: docusignapi

Can I create envelope and send envelope from Signer Account (using Signers User ID, Password, Integrator Key, Account ID). Template ID will be used from another user account after sharing the Templates.

When I try to create envelope from Signer's account "Invalid Template ID" error is coming.
Please let us know if I can create envelope from Signers Account and how it can be created.

Comment: Is this through the docusign api or through the web console?

Answer (score 0):

You can only share templates with members of the same account.  On top of that, I don't believe signer accounts (i.e. not sender accounts) can make use of templates, you would need to purchase a DocuSign account plan.